# How to start a Task class instance of MS TPL with some delay?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Which is more natural way to start a Task class instance of MS TPL with some delay?

```
Task logManager = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { // Some code }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

I just want to start it later in some seconds...

Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990602/what-is-the-correct-way-to-delay-the-start-of-a-task-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a timer so you don't waste thread processing time in the delay time:

```
Task logManager = null;
new Timer((state) =>
    {
        logManager = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /* Some code*/}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
```

Comment: I think your solution is the best one!

Answer (score 2):

```
int msDelay = 1000;
Task task = Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(msDelay); })
    .ContinueWith((Task starter) => { MessageBox.Show("Started after delay"); }, , TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Task logManager = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` will use a dedicated thread so blocking in this case won't effect any other thread