# Why does Task.Delay() allow an infinite delay?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

After my application froze I tracked down the cause to a thread waiting on a task created by `Task.Delay()` (or `TaskEx.Delay()` in .NET 4.0) for which it provided a computed `TimeSpan` that, due to a bug, was on occasion computed to a `TimeSpan` with a `TotalMilliseconds` of less than or equal to `-1` and greater than `-2` (i.e. anywhere between -10000 to -19999 ticks, inclusive).

It appears that when you pass a negative `TimeSpan` that is `-2` milliseconds or lower, the method correctly throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, but when you provide a negative TimeSpan from the range described above, it returns a `Task` that never completes (by setting the underlying `System.Threading.Timer` to a `dueTime` of -1 which denotes infinity). That means that any continuations set on that task will never execute, and any poor thread that happens to `.Wait()` on that `Task` will forever be blocked.

What possible use can a `Task` that never completes have? Would anyone expect such a return value? Shouldn't any negative value passed to `.Delay()`, including values in that special range, throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: The MSDN doc is pretty explicit in allowing -1, so it seems to be behaving correctly.  Not sure of the use case for that overload, but it could be a way of waiting for 'just' cancellation with the overload that takes a cancellation token.

Comment: @James: It is not explicit in allowing -1, it's explicit in disallowing values lower than -1. It doesn't even say what will happen if you pass -1, unlike the documentation of `System.Threading.Timer`. It almost appears like the documented list of exception was automatically generated from the source code. And if you're waiting for 'just' cancellation, why even make a call to `Task.Delay()`?

Comment: if you think it's broken, file a bug on connect.  A doc that says "lower than -1 is invalid" is explicit (to me) in saying that -1 is valid.  If the intent was -1 as invalid "lower than 0 is invalid" would have been easier to write.  Since the doc and the code both allow -1, I think this is By Design, but feel free to go file a bug on connect (more likely to be processed by the BCL team than a random SO thread, I would think :)

Comment: @James: The reason I posted it on SO is because I'm not sure it's a bug. I'm looking for an explanation for the design of this API, assuming it's intentional. For example, svick's use-case makes sense.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Timeout.Infinite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timeout.infinite.aspx) or -1 is useful when you want to wait indefinitely for a long-running task that will take an indeterminate amount of time to complete, but will eventually complete.

The Win32 API also uses a constant INFINITE = -1 for infinite timeouts.

You wouldn't normally want to use it in a UI thread, as it could freeze the UI (which seems to be your problem).  But there are valid use cases in a worker thread - e.g. a server that is blocking waiting for a connection from a client.

Comment: An infinite timeout is useful. An infinite delay is not (and therefore you first paragraph doesn't apply). What in the world would you want to delay forever? You might as well just not perform it. It just doesn't make any sense to me that the implementation detail of `-1` will be propagated from `System.Threading.Timer` (or the Win32 timer) up to the `Task.Delay()` method. It is contrary to Microsoft's design principle of pushing developers into the "pit of success", unless there’s some use case I’m not aware of.

Comment: Also, I'm not using it in a UI thread. It's a Windows Service that when asked to stop, it must perform a shutdown routine by calling a [TAP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957)-based method that may take too long to run so it also create a delay task that will perform a forced shutdown. It then performs a  `.WaitAny()` on both tasks, and since the original task took an extremely long time and the delay task will never complete (instead of throwing an exception), the service appeared to hang.

Comment: How would a server that is blocking waiting for a connection from a client would use a `Task` that never completes? Could you show an example?

Comment: @AllonGuralnek, you can do something like `await Task.WhenAny(mainTask, Task.Delay(timeout))`. And if you set `timeout` to -1, then it never times out.

Comment: @Joe, it will freeze the UI only if you `Wait()` on it. If you use it with `await`, it's just fine on the UI thread too.

Comment: @svick: I guess that's a valid use case, but it doesn't seem like it was in the mind of the developer who wrote `.Delay()`. Look at the [decompilation of `.Delay()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9068520/149265). The special cases return a special task, like in the case of a delay of 0 that returns a pre-completed task, and when passing an already-canceled `CancellationToken` returns a pre-canceled task. In both cases a `Timer` isn't created. But `-1` doesn't seem to be special-cased and a `Timer` *is* created even though it is not needed nor used. The whole thing just seems a bit fishy to me.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek, I think it quite possible that the case of -1 does not happen often enough to warrant optimization. Also, there might be some other reason why it's not a good idea to have a singleton task that never completes. It simply doesn't seem fishy to me at all.

Comment: I would vote for asking this at the MSDN forums, perhaps an MVP will answer it.

Comment: @everwicked: I think I can accept Joe/svick's use case as reasonable and plausible. You can still make a further inquiry on the MSDN Forums yourself if you'd like. Feel free to link to this question from there, add you own answer and even edit this question.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using it when I want console application not to terminate.
For example, when I'm writing a *Web Job* for Azure, I need a program that never terminates. Here's the template:

```
public async Task Main(string args[])
{
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 6000;
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // Do something repeatedly, each 1 minute.
    };
    timer.Start();

    // Now what to do to stop the application from terminating!?
    // That's the magic:
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In mocking scenarios, where I want to ensure that my code in a Task.WhenAny() block is handling one of the tasks awaited on correctly, I may mock the other tasks and use an infinite delay to ensure that the Task.WhenAny is processing the task I did not mock as an infinite delay.

Comment: Interesting use-case, although I think it would be more explicit and clear to use `new TaskCompletionSource().Task` to provide a never-ending task.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek another way of creating a never ending task is by using the `Task` constructor with an empty delegate: `new Task(() => {})`. The task will never complete because it will never be started.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias until someone sneaky calls `.Start()` on it 