# C# delayed (async) execution without reliability across restarts

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, asynchronous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to delay the start of a Task in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990602/what-is-the-correct-way-to-delay-the-start-of-a-task-in-c-sharp)

I need to schedule small tasks to be executed in the future (delay is always < 1minute). Implementation is in .NET on the .NET 4.0 runtime. Async ctp is an option, although I don't see the added value for the moment.

- the scheduling needs to be async
- scheduling resolution is in seconds
- the task execution is implicitly async (i think)
- the number of scheduled tasks could be in the hundreds or even thousands
- it is possible, however unlikely, that two tasks will be scheduled at the exact same time

My current solution is this:

```
internal class TimerState
{
    internal Timer Timer { get; set; }
    internal object Payload { get; set; }
    internal Action<object> Action { get; set; }
}

public class TimerModule
{
    public static void ScheduleTask(object input, Action<object> action, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        //create state to pass to timer method
        var state = new TimerState { Payload = input, Action = action };

        //schedule timer without firing 
        var t = new Timer(HandleScheduleTimer, state, -1, -1);

        //add timer to state to be able to dispose it
        state.Timer = t;

        //schedule timer to fire in delay time
        t.Change(delay, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
    }


    private static void HandleScheduleTimer(object state)
    {
        var s = state as TimerState;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(s.Action, s.Payload, CancellationToken.None,
                              TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, TaskScheduler.Current);

        //dispose the timer immediately
        if(s.Timer != null)
            s.Timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I've done some tests with performance counters (.NET physical threads), but I don't see that many threads running at the same time, even though I schedule thousands of tasks at approximately the same time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Are there any proven design patterns around this?

Mostly I've found scheduling to be reliable across restarts, but I don't need that, I can replay the data in the system after a crash and compensate for the scheduled tasks that weren't executed.

**Edit**: I don't mean that I *want* to see thousands of threads running at the same time. I'm aware that this will probably be handled with the threadpool. Like I say in the comments, a test with 5M tasks spanned over 100 seconds only sees an increase of 20 in the physical threads.

My main question is this: is there a better way to delay task execution?

Comment: How many threads do you see? and how many cores do you have?

Comment: I'm running 5M tasks scheduled in the space of 100 seconds. I have 3 cores and I see around 180 physical threads (global counter). the content of the tasks is going to be sub-second work. Is it ok to substitute the work with sleep in a test?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990602/what-is-the-correct-way-to-delay-the-start-of-a-task-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: I would say that 180 threads **is a lot**, especially if you only have 3 cores. You should not expect a thread per item - that isn't how it works. More threads is not *faster*, and each thread takes non-trivial resources (the stack alone is a big chunk). So: a *pool* of threads is employed to service multiple tasks. You can't do more CPU work than you have cores, and performance would significantly *degrade* - all the time would be spent thread-switching rather than doing actual work.

Comment: Also, if you expect to see thousands of threads you will be dissapointed as Tasks != Threads.

Comment: +1 for the other question, even though I searched for some time, I hadn't found it

Comment: @MarcGravell: what I meant to say was: when starting a test, I see a bump from 160 to approx 180 physical threads. So my test is only using 20 or so to run.

Comment: My fault for not saying that earlier, sorry.

Comment: @StephaneT wait.... your idle process has 160 threads? you should have... about 6-to-10

Comment: You're right, when I isolate the process in perfmon, it starts out with 6 and jumps to 20 threads when the tasks start executing, jumping up again to 35 after a while

Answer (score 1):

The solution you're looking for is Quartz.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

It's a very robust scheduler capable of handling different jobs tied to different schedules. It is far more reliable than a timer. It has failover if anything goes wrong.

The schedules either use a CRON interval or can run on specific dates.  I've heard of instances having thousands of jobs.  Quartz can be clustered if need be, and can run stateful (keeping knowledge of previous instances) and non-stateful jobs.  Depending on how they're configured, they can run simultaneously or in a queue.  Most thread and thread safety issues have been taken care of for you, you're free to write your job class without  headache.

Set up is simple (install service, and configure), creating quartz jobs are even simpler.  Create a class that inherits from IJob, apply your logic, and add it to the quartz config.  Config can be an xml file, sql server database, or you can create your own solution.  I'm working on one for RavenDB.