# Is there a way to time out a method earlier in c# mvc?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller

I am calling a method that will send an email via SMTP to the user to verify their account. I put this in a try catch block so that if it fails it will give the user an error message. 
However the time for it to time out is much longer than I would like.
I would like to reduce the time for the method to fail to maybe 10 seconds so the user isn't waiting for something that is already going to fail.

Is there a way to shorten the wait time so that it falls into the catch faster?

```
try
{
    SendVerificationLinkEmail(dbUser.Username, dbUser.ActivationCode.ToString());
}
catch
{
    ViewBag.Message = "There was an error sending your verification email. Please try again later or contact Tech Support.";
    return View("CreateAccount", new UserViewModel());
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18597520

Comment: You may want to reduce the time-out of the SMTP client you are using inside your SendVerificationLinkEmail. That way, it will fail quicker. Even better, skip using SMTP and use a transactional email sending service such as Mandrill, SendGrid, MailGun etc. Their API calls will be quicker and fail less than SMTP.