# Is there an alternative to Task.Delay(0) and Task.FromResult(0)?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, portable-class-library, base-class-library

I am attempting to create a Portable Class Library (.NET 4.5/Silverlight 5/Win Phone 8/WinRT) that takes advantage of the async/await feature set. I found that I need to include the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package in order to get this feature to work, so I did just that. Apparently due to my targets I do not have access to `Task.Delay(0)` or `Task.FromResult(0)`. I was wondering what the next best alternative is?

Currently, I am using: `new Task(() => { })` (basically, a Task that does not perform any action.)

I'm not sure if that is the best equivalent to either of the previously mentioned patterns.

---

**Update: Apparently I'm blind and did not see `TaskEx` in my intellisense menu. I'm leaving the question open so people know that it is there, just easily missable because my intellisense kept autocompleting to `TaskExtensions`.**

Comment: What's the purpose of `Task.Delay(0)`?

Comment: Depending on that purpose, it's quite possible that `Task.Yield` (`TaskEx.Yield`?) is more appropriate.

Comment: Also related: [How to put a task to sleep (or delay) in C# 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341962/how-to-put-a-task-to-sleep-or-delay-in-c-sharp-4-0/15342256#15342256)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`FromResult` and `Delay` are on the `TaskEx` type in the Microsoft.Bcl.Async library.