# Call Thread.Sleep from the Task

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, delay, thread-sleep

Is it correct to use Thread.Sleep() inside the task. Or is only a timer (Task.Delay() in .Net 4.5 and latter) used with task? Or maybe another approaches exist.

Comment: The question is what do you want to achieve? As there are pros and cons to all approaches.

Comment: You can but it's a very bad practice because you are disabling a ThreadPool thread that could be used to server other tashs. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MattWilko I think SerG is looking for an alternative to Task.Delay() for .NET 4.0 as that was introduced in .NET 4.5.

Comment: If you're looking for Task.Delay in [.Net4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15342256/2530848)

Comment: Serg, is it for .NET 4.0? also do you want a `CancellationToken`?

Comment: It's for .NET 4.0, but question is about right way to pause a task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* use `Thread.Sleep` inside a task.
But in most situations I'd prefer to use `await Task.Delay` which does not block the thread.

If you're using `Task.Run` (which uses a ThreadPool thread), then you should try not to block the thread. As it is a shared thread, there may be other code waiting to run.

I would still use `Thread.Sleep(0)` when I'm done using the thread, to yield the processor and give up your time slice.

Comment: Indeed, you *can* use it, but as far as the OP goes I would say it is definitely "not correct" to sleep a task pool thread when it could be handling other work!

Comment: dcastro, are you sure that Sleep(0) is not removed during the optimization by a compiler as meaningless redundant statement? I haven't found any information in msdn about such trick.

Comment: @SerG From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx): "Specify zero (0) to indicate that this thread should be suspended to allow other waiting threads to execute."

Answer (score 2):

It seems the real question is how to achieve the same effect as .NET 4.5's `Task.Delay` in .NET 4.0.

First, if you use Visual Studio 2012+ you can add the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) nuget package to your project to enable `async/await` and other new functionality like Task.Delay. This is the most convenient method.

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you can achieve the same results by creating a TaskCompletionSource that completes when a timer expires. This is already provided by the [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://github.com/ChadBurggraf/parallel-extensions-extras/blob/master/Extensions/TaskFactoryExtensions/TaskFactoryExtensions_Delayed.cs) library as a set of extension methods.

The basic function is `StartNewDelayed` and there are many convenience overloads:

```
    /// <summary>Creates a Task that will complete after the specified delay.</summary>
    /// <param name="factory">The TaskFactory.</param>
    /// <param name="millisecondsDelay">The delay after which the Task should transition to RanToCompletion.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token that can be used to cancel the timed task.</param>
    /// <returns>A Task that will be completed after the specified duration and that's cancelable with the specified token.</returns>
    public static Task StartNewDelayed(this TaskFactory factory, int millisecondsDelay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Validate arguments
        if (factory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");
        if (millisecondsDelay < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("millisecondsDelay");

        // Check for a pre-canceled token
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return factory.FromCancellation(cancellationToken);

        // Create the timed task
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(factory.CreationOptions);
        var ctr = default(CancellationTokenRegistration);

        // Create the timer but don't start it yet.  If we start it now,
        // it might fire before ctr has been set to the right registration.
        var timer = new Timer(self =>
        {
            // Clean up both the cancellation token and the timer, and try to transition to completed
            try
            {
                ctr.Dispose();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                // Eat this. Mono throws a NullReferenceException when constructed with
                // default(CancellationTokenRegistration);
            }

            ((Timer)self).Dispose();
            tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        });

        // Register with the cancellation token.
        if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled)
        {
            // When cancellation occurs, cancel the timer and try to transition to canceled.
            // There could be a race, but it's benign.
            ctr = cancellationToken.Register(() =>
            {
                timer.Dispose();
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            });
        }

        // Start the timer and hand back the task...
        try { timer.Change(millisecondsDelay, Timeout.Infinite); }
        catch(ObjectDisposedException) {} // in case there's a race with cancellation; this is benign

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Most of the code deals with properly disposing of the timer and handling cancellations.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.5 you should use `Task.Delay`. In .NET 4.0, since it doesn't have `Task.Delay` and `Thread.Sleep` inside a Task is a bad practice... create a custom task, and use a timer to mark ti as completed.