# async/await - Is this understanding correct?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

After two questions and much confusion - I wonder if I finally got it right. This is my understanding:

`async/await` serves *only one purpose* - to allow code to be executed after an *already* asynchronous task is finished.
e.g.

```
async Task CallerMethod()
{
     await AsyncMethod();
     AnotherMethod();
}
```

allows `AnotherMethod` to be executed after the asynchronous `AsyncMethod` is *finished* instead of immediately after `AsyncMethod` is *started*.

async/await NEVER *makes* anything asynchronous. It doesn't start a separate thread (unless the awaited method does that anyway, of course), etc.

Is my understanding (finally) correct?

Comment: yes that sounds about right - but please note that you can end up on another thread even if `AsyncMethod` does not spawn threads - your callback can be spawned in any threadpool-thread

Comment: @Carsten Thanks. Assuming that by `callback` you mean `AnotherMethod();` - that would have a very important implication - that I couldn't update the UI from it - is that really true?

Comment: No, you can safely update the UI from it. The reason for this is that each Thread has a `SynchronizationContext` that is used by the code generated by async/await to dispatch the callback that finishes the async method. In the case of WPF (for example), that class is a `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` that makes sure to invoke the method back to the Dispatcher thread if necessary. There's a similar class for WinForms.

Comment: @TimDestan Thanks for clarifying that up!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Though Stephen's answer is correct, I want to make sure that you've got a few additional points clear.

> async/await NEVER makes anything asynchronous

It makes `CallerMethod` an asynchronous method. `CallerMethod` returns a `Task` which can itself be awaited, and `CallerMethod` returns that task before the work of `CallerMethod` is itself complete, so it is an asynchronous method.

It doesn't make `AsyncMethod` asynchronous; it was already asynchronous.

> It doesn't start a separate thread

Right. This is a frequent source of confusion. Threads are a unit of concurrency, which is only one kind of asynchrony. An analogy usually helps. You can put the bread in the toaster, wait for it to get toasted, and then make the eggs. You can put the bread in the toaster, cook the eggs while the toast is toasting, and then deal with the toast after the eggs are done.  Or you can hire two cooks, one to cook eggs and one to make toast.  The first is synchronous processing. The second and third are asynchronous, but only the third is concurrent. Notice that the third solution is the most expensive; threads are workers and workers aren't cheap.

What makes an asynchronous method asynchronous is not that it is concurrent -- though it might be. What makes it asynchronous is that it gives you a mechanism that allows you to *do something else while you're waiting for its work to complete*. `await` is just a pleasant way to write "here's the code I want you to run after the task has completed successfully".

Comment: Thanks. I would note, though, that when some say "thread" - they (us) might not be referring to actual threads (as in your 3rd analogy). They are rather, referring to anytime two operations are concurrent, wrapping your 2nd and 3rd analogies together. So whether it's an actual thread, or just the disk drive working - they would consider this "multithreading". Anyway - not arguing about anything here, it's just some (perhaps correct) information that can help you help others. Thanks again!

Comment: @ispiro: That in itself alludes to a common misconception; Stephen has a great article debunking the idea that hardware I/O is somehow multithreaded, and I can certainly do no better than to refer you to it. Do a search on "Stephen Cleary there is no thread", and you'll find it.

Comment: It's semantics, but I think *concurrent* isn't the best word here. We would usually call both the second and third options concurrent as 2 operations are being performed at the same time but only call the third *parallel* as it requires multiple chefs (or threads) running in parallel. 

Hence the expression: "Single Threaded Concurrency".

Comment: Thank you Eric, for the analogy. It is always confusing me who does what. In your second example, while I am cooking the eggs, which thread is doing the toasting? If it is me, should I compare it like: as long as I have to do something with the toaster I can't start cooking eggs, so while I am inserting the bread and switching the toaster on I can't cook the eggs. As soon as the toaster sees an await, I start cooking eggs. When finished cooking I can check if the toaster is finished and if not wait for it? So am I the only one who is doing all the work?

Comment: @i3arnon: Sure, that's a good point. There can be concurrent -- at the same time -- operations happening without an additional thread, if, say, hardware is performing the concurrent operation.

Comment: @HaraldDutch: In my analogy a thread is a worker -- a person. There is no thread doing the toasting. A toaster is not a person; it operates *below* the level of persons. Just as you don't ask "which thread is running my hard disk?"  No thread is running your hard disk; the hard disk operates in a world *below* the level of threads. When you "await" a disk operation, there is no "disk thread" that is running in the background.  The Stephen Cleary article I mentioned above might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 7):

> async/await NEVER makes anything asynchronous. It doesn't start a separate thread (unless the awaited method does that anyway, of course), etc.

Yes.

Put another way, `async`/`await` enables writing code from an asynchronous perspective. That is, code can "asynchronously wait" (`await`) operations to complete, and in turn define its own asynchronous operation (the task returned from an `async` method, which represents the execution of that method).