# Execute a Method after completion of any one task in c#

Tags: c#

i have two tasks running asynchronously.

```
var task1=Task.Run(async()=>{method1();});
var task2=Task.Run(async()=>{method1();});
```

If any one of the task completed,i want to run an another method(eg:method2()).And after completion of second task,  i want to  run the same method again(i.e.,method2()) .How to do this?

Comment: so do you want to run method2 twice? After task1 and after task2?

Comment: How about simply `async() => { method1(); method2(); }` ?

Comment: Like `Task.WhenAny(..:)`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Does method1 return a task? Why do you have the `async` marker in the `run` when you don't await anything inside it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call one task after completion of multiple tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347177/how-to-call-one-task-after-completion-of-multiple-tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If any one of the task completed,i want to run an another method(eg:method2()).And after completion of second task, i want to run the same method again(i.e.,method2())

Sounds like you have two parallel paths of execution, each composed of two method calls in series. So....

```
var task1 = Task.Run( async () => { await method1(); await method2(); });  
var task2 = Task.Run( async () => { await method1(); await method2(); });  

await Task.WhenAll( new Task[] { task1, task2 } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your methods are awaitable, Maybe you want something like this

```
await Task.WhenAny(method1,method1); // wait for something to finish
await method2(); // await for method 2
await Task.WhenAll(method1,method1); // run it all again

// or endlessly
while(!theEndofTheUniverse)
{
   await Task.WhenAny(method1,method1);
   await method2();
} // rinse and repeate
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to remove the completed Task from the List for the next call to `WhenAny`? I thought that if there is an already completed Task in the passed collection , `WhenAny` will return immediatly with that completed Task? Unfortunately this isn't explicitly stated in WhenAny's docs ... (or I didn't find it)

Comment: @Fildor in this situation its just passing in hot tasks, though in general i am not comfortable with this question or my answer

Comment: Totally agreed. That's why I didn't post an answer. It looks kind of odd.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have a bunch of tasks and if one of them is finshed you want to run another task?

You can use `Task.WhenAny()`. It accepts an array of tasks and you can await until the first one is finished

```
var tasks = new[] { Method1(), Method2(), Method3() };
await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
await Method4();
```

MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: when first task completed,it starts to run method4().If second task completed,is it call method4() again?

Comment: No only after the first task has finished. You will just await until the first task is finished.

Comment: sorry,i don't understand what  you are trying to say?

Comment: Method4() is only called once (after one of the tasks provided in `tasks` is finished). All other tasks will not be awaited.