# Xamarin.ios iphone device Current location(street address)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
    public static async Task<Position> GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        try
        {

            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;


            if (!locator.IsGeolocationAvailable)
                throw new NotSupportedException("Geolocation not available");
            if (!locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
                throw new GeolocationException(GeolocationError.PositionUnavailable);


            return await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 100000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Add error logging
            return null;
        }
    }
```

on `return await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 100000);`
the thread exit and debugger not return but the output window shows the location correctly but didn't return to the code. What should be the possible reason for this break?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375413/program-exits-upon-calling-await

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you would like to know why your async code behaves the way it does?

Let's first get the terminology right: there is [no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) that exits. Async/await is not about threads but about orchestrating asynchronous operations.

Your code returns at the `await` if the `Task` you are waiting for has not completed yet. Later, execution will then be picked up after the [awaited](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) code. In your case, the only thing that will happen is that the result of the task (= the location) will be returned.

So in any case, your method will exit:

- either because the task is not complete yet
- or because it is complete and you are using `return`