# Can't read API response content

Tags: c#

Why do my breakpoints skip after:

```
 var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

I can't log anything in or after this line of code, it just continues the application with no error message and no returned type. I've tried different methods of reading the response content, but each just jumps out of debug mode with no result.

I'm expecting a json object in the body content.

```
        public async Task<PagingResponse<AssetResult>> UploadMultiAsset(MultipartFormDataContent body)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var response = await _client.PostAsync("api/upload", body))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var metaData = JsonSerializer
                        .Deserialize<MetaData>(response.Headers.GetValues("X-Pagination").First(), _options);

                    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();                    

                    var pagingResponse = new PagingResponse<AssetResult>
                    {
                        Items = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<AssetResult>>(stream, _options),
                        MetaData = metaData
                    };

                    return pagingResponse;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }           
        }
```

Comment: Just remove the debug folder and rebuild, It should solve the problem

Comment: Does [Program exits upon calling await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375413/program-exits-upon-calling-await) help?