# Why isn't all of the data being logged?

Tags: c#, file

I have a `List<Passenger>` that contains information about their trips with my bus.
Each time I perform a trip I generate a random number of passengers (anywhere from 0 to 10) and I record them when they exit the bus.

I run the program anywhere between 10 to 100.000 times and record the passengers to the list only when they exit the bus. On the final stop, everyone gets kicked out.

I then use this code to write every passenger's trip to a text file.

##### Code

This code get called directly inside `static void Main` of `Program.cs` right after the cycles have completed running.

```
private static async Task LogData(StatManager statManager)
{
    await File.WriteAllLinesAsync("test_output_1.txt", statManager.LogAllData());
}
```

##### Passenger.cs

```
public int ID {get; private set;}
public int stops {get; private set;} = 0;
public TripInfo trip {get; private set;} 
public Passenger(int passenger_id, int stop_entered)
{
    ID = passenger_id;
    trip = new TripInfo();
    trip.first_stop = stop_entered;
}

public void ExitBus(int exit_stop)
{
    //get called once the passenger exits the bus
    //at this point, the passenger is added to the main list
    trip.exit_stop = exit_stop;
}

public void ArrivedAtStop()
{
    stops++; //stop counter
}

public int[] GetStopsVisited()
{
    int[] stops = new int[trip.stop_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < trip.stop_count; i++)
    {
        stops[i] = trip.first_stop + i;
    }
    return stops;
}

public class TripInfo
{
    public int first_stop;
    public int exit_stop;
    public int stop_count
    {
        get
        {
            if (exit_stop == null) return -1;
            return exit_stop - first_stop;
        }
    }
}
```

##### StatManager.cs

```
public List<Passenger> LifetimePassengers = new List<Passenger>();
public int LifetimePassengerCount {get; private set;} = 0; //gets incremented in every cycle
private float mean;
private int LifetimeStops
{
    get
    {
        return busManager.CurrentStop + 1; //gets an int that was incremented in every cycle
    }
}
public String[] LogAllData()
{
    List<String> toLog = new List<string>();
    toLog.Add("LifetimeStops:"+LifetimeStops.ToString());
    toLog.Add("LifetimePassengers:"+LifetimePassengerCount.ToString());
    toLog.Add("IndividualPassengerData");
    foreach(Passenger p in LifetimePassengers)
    {
        toLog.Add("-");
        toLog.Add($"PassengerID:{p.ID}");
        toLog.Add($"NumberOfStops:{p.stops}");
        toLog.Add($"FirstStop:{p.trip.first_stop}");
        toLog.Add($"ExitStop:{p.trip.exit_stop}");
        string stops = String.Join(",", p.GetStopsVisited());
        toLog.Add($"StopsVisited:[{stops}]");
    }
    return toLog.ToArray();
}
```

Output is as expected for the first lines but then I get this:

> ...
> PassengerID:677
> NumberOfStops:2
> FirstStop:198
> ExitStop:200
> StopsVisited:[198,199]
> PassengerID:678
> NumberOfStops:2
> FirstStop:198
> ExitStop:200
> StopsVisited:[198,199]
> PassengerID:679
> NumberOfStops:1
> Fi

All data follows the above pattern of an ID and some trip information. But the data is incomplete. Above, the last passenger recorded is number 679 but the program ran for 1.000 stops and had a minimum of 1.000 passengers. Also the data stops abruptly with this unexpected `Fi` and does not complete the record of passenger number 679.

Furthermore, when I tried re-running the program, it did not output anything. I tried running it for amount of cycles: 5, 10 and 100, there was no difference and there was no output.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to follow this pattern calling async method from the main:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task MainAsync()
{
     // 
    var statManager = new StatManager();
    // you code here ...
    await LogData(statManager);
}
private static async Task LogData(StatManager statManager)
{
    await File.WriteAllLinesAsync("test_output_1.txt", 
    statManager.LogAllData());
}
```

Comment: I am unsure about how to proceed with what you recommend. Could you explain a little further so I can try it?

Comment: you can try it by copying whatever you have in Main() to MainAsync shown above, that's all

Comment: He means to call like `LogData(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`; To block the thread before `LogData()` is completed. There are similar ways to do so like `.Wait()`, there are discussions about those different ways on internet if you're interested. If you don't have other jobs to do after `LogData()` is called, you can also make `LogData` not async method. By making it block first, you can check if the method is working as you thought, then you can look into if the issue is caused by asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thanks a lot. I don't understand why though.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang I made this project to understand more about `async` and `await`. I knew I could solve it by avoiding such behavior, but I still wanted to learn how to approach such problems.

Comment: For future reference: I tried using this solution in my original code. Adding `LogData(statManager).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` was enough for the problem to be solved.
After all it seems I had to make the program wait for the logging to finish before proceeding, and I was doing that wrong.
Regardless, thanks for all the help!

Comment: The `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` way is actually a mean to easily run async methods synchronously. According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375413/program-exits-upon-calling-await) async jobs can end early if main process is exited. By the way, `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` also have a benefit that it can return actual `Exception` from the function called, while other ways to wait for result (such as `.Wait()`) returns `AggregatedException`. But it's not officially recommended to use while coding - I'd suggest work around `async await` if you can.