# Tasks on Framework 4.0: Put a timeout on the innermost task in a chain of continuations

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I was looking for a Task based way to detect a timeout for a task, without having to `Wait()` for it.

The timeout should be put **on the innermost task** in a chain of continuations, while the Exception should get caught only at the outermost level.

My solution, instead of blocking the execution, returns a Task which wraps the original one, allowing the user to catch an exception in case of time out.

So I came up with this code:

```
public static Task<T> Timeout<T>(Task<T> baseTask,  int milliseconds)
{
    var timer = Delay(milliseconds);

    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(
        new []
        {
            baseTask,
            timer.ContinueWith<T>(x => { throw new TaskTimeOutException(); })
        },
        x => x.Result
    );
}
```

The function `Delay()` is described in the accepted solution at [How to put a task to sleep (or delay) in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341962/how-to-put-a-task-to-sleep-or-delay-in-c-sharp-4-0) .

I would like to improve my code, basically I have a few questions:

- Can someone see possible pitfalls?
- Should the timeout cause a cancellation of the original Task?

Thank you.

### EDIT

Based on comments I developed this slight improvement:

```
public static Task<T> Timeout<T>(Task<T> baseTask,  int milliseconds)
{
    var timer = Delay(milliseconds);

    return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(
        new []
        {
            baseTask,
            timer
        },
        x =>
        {
            if (x.Equals(baseTask)) return baseTask.Result;
            throw new TaskTimeOutException();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: there is one little issue: if timeoutexception will be thrown there is "no catch" block that catch it beacause that exception will be thronw in one detached thread. I've found this problem and i've resolved this problem managing the unandletapplication exception event.

Comment: You mean that if the original tasks succedes the timer would still fire the exception, making it impossible to catch?
Because I think that, if the original task fails to complete in time, the exception can be catched by user code, as the result of the composite task.

Comment: I've wrote a simple test program, see it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create task with `CancellationToken` and then call `tokenSource.CancelAfter(...)` like this

```
var tokeSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("processing"); }, tokenSource.Token);
tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

In .Net 4.0 you can implement `CancelAfter` by yourself with something like

```
public static class CancellationTokenSourceExtensions
{
    public static Task CancelAfter(this CancellationTokenSource cts, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return Task.Delay(timeout).ContinueWith(t => cts.Cancel());
    }
}
```

I personally think that `cts`-based solution is more with the spirit of TPL.

Comment: Thank you but CancelAfter does not seem to be available in Framework 4.0

Comment: @AndreaRossini sorry, i thought it should be available in 4.0. I added extended example of how you can try to implement `CancelAfter` by yourself.

Comment: Useful example. I will surely use it somewhere in the future.

Comment: Thanks. It has following advantages over solution with `ContinueWhenAny`: 1. You actually try to cancel timed out task. 2. You can use `.IsCanceled` on task object

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static bool continueRun = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter code");
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter task");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("End thread sleep");
                    throw new Exception("Inner task execution");
                });
                Console.WriteLine("Exit code");
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception code");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finally code");
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Unhandled exception");
            continueRun = false;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Ouput:

```
Enter code
Exit  code
Finally code
Press a key to exit
Enter Task
End thread sleep
```

in visual studio you'll see raising of one uncatched exception

Comment: The runtime treats your Exception as unhandled because your example actually fire-and-forgets the Task. I **always** wait my tasks in some top level, so I can catch Exceptions in well-defined points.

Comment: My bad, I should rename the question. What I wanted was to put the timeout at the innermost task, without waiting it, so the exception could propagate to the first block of code waiting for it.