# Stopwatch vs Task.Wait

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, stopwatch

Note: I am restricted to .net 4.0

I am currently using stopwatch to measure the time it takes for an action to run.
After the action completes, I do logic based on the time. More specificaly, I check if the time went beyond a certain threshold.

I recently discovered the Task.Wait(int timeout) method

Is it better to put my action in a task and wait for it on my threshold?

for example:

```
bool isOnTime=false;
Task action = new Task(() => someMethod());
action.Start();
isOnTime = action.Wait(myThreshold);

if(!isOnTime)
{
...some code
}
```

Edit: Updating the question since everyone thinks i want to run a task

This is how i currently do it:

```
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
someMethod();
watch.Stop();
executeTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

later i am running:

```
if (executeTime > Threshold)
```

I am running the method synchronously and i want to keep it that way

Comment: Are you measuring time (then use `Stopwatch`) or are you implementing timeouts (then `Task.Wait` might be ok)?

Comment: It is fine if the action runs for longer than my threshold, but i want to know if it went beyond

Comment: Shouldn't then the part telling you that be a part of method?

Answer (score 1):

What happens now is that if the action takes longer than myThreshold, the action will be cancelled. I don't think that is what you want. Besides that, you are also blocking the calling thread by using `.Wait()`.

I'd say stick to the stopwatch or think of something else.

Edit: my bad, my understanding of `Task.Wait()` is not correct. I learned something today, so that's good :-)

Still, unless someMethod is an async method, you are using another thread. So if concurrency is not a problem, it would be a nice option.

Comment: Task.Wait(int timeout) does not cancel the task.
It cancels the Wait after the timeout

Comment: It's in general not possible to cancel any .NET code without the code cooperating. This is important to realize.

Answer (score 1):

> It is fine if the action runs for longer than my threshold

It seems what you want to run it asynchronously, then `Task.Wait` is more appropriate as you get information about timeout as soon as happens (while method may still run longer).

You can use wrapper method to run similar to

```
bool IsCompletedInTime(Action action, int msTimeout) =>
    Task.Run(() => action()).Wait(msTimeout);
```

Usage:

```
if(!IsCompletedInTime(someMethod, myThreshold))
{
    ... // timeout
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonable approach. You can abandon the task after a timeout.

The problem with that is that the task might consume resources or cause side effects after the timeout. It's generally better to implement a cancellation scheme and cancel the task:

```
var cts = new CTS();
var task = Task.Run(() => F(cts.Token));
cts.CancelAfter(...);
task.Wait();
```

Here, we are *always* waiting on the task to ensure that it is shut down. It's the responsibility of `F` to ensure timely cancellation.

That way we can avoid all concurrency issues caused by a possibly rogue task.

Comment: I do not want to cancel the task

Comment: In that case the task machinery is not necessary. Use the Stopwatch solution. Do you see any problems with it? Seems simple.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should avoid blocking by using a continuation to handle how long the task took to complete.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            var task = new Task(() => 
            {
                sw.Start();
                someMethod();
            });

            task.Start();

            task.ContinueWith(antecedent => 
            {
                if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 1000 )
                    Console.WriteLine("Took at least second.");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Took less than a second.");
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void someMethod()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you won't be blocking any tasks while waiting for the task to complete.

Comment: Do not use Thread.Sleep if you are working with tasks, use the delay method if .net4.5, otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341962/how-to-put-a-task-to-sleep-or-delay-in-c-sharp-4-0

Comment: @Enfantcool This is just something to simulate the thread taking some time; it's completely unnecessary to use Thread.Delay() in this context. In any case, look at the top row of the OP: **Note: I am restricted to .net 4.0**

Comment: @Enfantcool I have rejected your edit; it's not really appropriate for this answer. The contents of `someMethod()` is immaterial other than it must take longer than a second to return - the point is to show that you can use `.ContinueWith()` to achieve what you want.

Comment: You are running the task asynchronously in your answer. Tasks do not guarantee a separate thread. You could be putting the main thread to sleep if you use Thread.Sleep(2000); The point is if i took your code and copy pasted it, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Enfantcool It works in the Console application in this answer because the default TaskScheduler will create a new thread.The contents of `someMethod()` that you will be using will of course be the one in your code rather than the code here, so it wouldn't contain the `Thread.Sleep()`. You're focusing on the wrong thing - the point to take away is that you can use `Task.ContinueWith()` to solve the issue. You certainly wouldn't be copy/pasting the contents of `someMethod()` into your actual code, would you?