# Time delays without using Thread.sleep()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, multidimensional-array

I wrote a client application where I am using two threads other than the main thread.The Background thread is used to receive data through TCP IP,while after receiving I am calling another thread that will show the received data continuously using a for loop.But after every iteration the for loop needs to wait for 30 seconds.I have used Thread.sleep(30000) but the dont know why its not working,sometimes it wakes up from sleep mode before 30 seconds.I am using dot net framework 4.Please suggest some other alternatives.

```
 for(n=0;n<=m;n++)
 {
   //show data;
   //wait for 30 seconds
 }
```

Comment: You have several options. You could even write you own tímer using DateTime and a Loop, if you don't like `Task.Delay` or `Thread.Sleep`. There are also `Timer`-classes, which might help you.

Comment: Without *any* indication *how* you wait for 30 seconds, you expect us to know what's wrong? If you have problems with code not showing expected behavior, **post the code**.

Comment: As I said I used Thread.Sleep() there.My code looked like - for(n=0;n<=m;n++)
 {
   //show data;
   Thread.Sleep(30000);
 }

Comment: I think it's too late but here is another way

  Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, yourSecondsAsInt)).ContinueWith(t => { YourMethodToExecute(); });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timers are not accurate in .NET . You might not get 30000 exactly.

You can using `Thread.Sleep(30000`); Or `await Task.Delay(30000)` but you need to mark your method as `async`;

The difference is that `Thread.Sleep` block the current thread, while Task.Delay doesn't.

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    int n;
    int m = 100;

    for(n=0; n<=m; n++)
    {
        //show data;
        //wait for 30 seconds
        await Task.Delay(30000);
    }
}
```

For .NET 4, you can use this [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341962/how-to-put-a-task-to-sleep-or-delay-in-c-sharp-4-0):

```
public static Task Delay(double milliseconds)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += (obj, args) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    };
    timer.Interval = milliseconds;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Start();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: I cant use Task.Delay() as I am using .Net Framework 4,and Task.Delay() is used in framework 4.5

Comment: @SubhodeepBhattacharjee check the edit

Comment: Thank you Sir,This one worked perfectly ..Thanks so much :)

Comment: you don't have await in .net 4, thus the second version of delay can not be used in a for loop.