# Delay execution of a method using Thread in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

I need to delay the execution of a method for few seconds using Thread.

But when I use `Thread.Sleep(1000);` it blocks the UI execution.

Somebody suggest me to  use `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();`. But it doesn't work in the framework 4.0. 
I can do this using Timer. But I need to achieve this using Thread.

As I was a fresher I can't able to understand the answers provided in the similar questions.

Can any one tell me how to achieve the delayed execution of a method without blocking the UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I can do this using Timer. But I need to achieve this using Thread" - What's wrong with timer callbacks? Why do you want to create separate thread?

Comment: Why doesn't timer work for you? More information would be better - what sort of application (I assume winforms or wpf desktop?)

Comment: The method I need to delay will be called for every keypress. It is like searching a name from the list.

Comment: @MohanramAnbukkarasu: well, it's better to ask superior about his requirement. As it stated, it looks very strange. According to your comments, timer is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.@Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You need to **await** the task in order to avoid blocking the ui thread.

```
await Task.Delay(1000)
```

Comment: check this implementation of Task.Delay in .net 4: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341962/how-to-put-a-task-to-sleep-or-delay-in-c-sharp-4-0