# Toggling Checkbox on Timer/Delay Without Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 checkboxes. `Checkbox_toggle`, when checked, will initiate a toggle sequence. This toggle sequence will check and uncheck `Checkbox_control` with a timer/delay.

I want that to keep looping as long as Checkbox_toggle is checked. However, Thread.Sleep won't work for my purposes as I need the rest of the program to continue running. I looked into `BackgroundWorker` and I can't quite find an example/I don't understand it well enough to apply it to my program. I'm using .NET 4.0 so I can't use `Task.Delay`.

I know with `BackgroundWorker` there's the `ProgressChanged` event that can be used to update the UI, but I'm not really sure how I would be able to use that for my  application. I'm also open to another solution that isn't `BackgroundWorker`.

I tried using this .NET 4.0 implementation of Task.Delay, but it's not working how I'd like. It runs through all of that but the delay doesn't actually delay the loop

```
    public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task Delay(double milliseconds)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += (obj, args) =>
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        };
        timer.Interval = milliseconds;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Start();
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private void Checkbox_toggle_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (Checkbox_toggle.Checked == true)
        {
            Checkbox_control.Checked = true;
            Delay(1000);
            Checkbox_control.Checked = false;
            Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

Task delay event found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15342256/8407531

My actual question: How can I toggle a checkbox on a timer without using Thread.Sleep, or how can I offset it to another thread? If possible, this delay needs to be adjustable from the other thread.

Comment: Don't use a `BackgroundWorker`, use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstood the use of the timer. Normally you would set up the `Timer` with an interval, and if you want repeated actions then you would set `timer.AutoReset = true`.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.AutoReset = true;

    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

    timer.Start();
}
```

Now when you start the timer now it will wait until the interval is over then it will fire the `Elapsed` event and perform some action in the eventhandler that you implemented when you registered the event:

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // here you can specify whether the toggeling should occur or not
    if (Checkbox_toggle.Checked)
    {
        // toggling needs to be invoked since it is called on a different thread
        this.checkBox_Control.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(() => this.checkBox_Control.Checked = !this.checkBox_Control.Checked));
    }
}
```

The timer will continue to run, without freezing your GUI. And you can simply check or uncheck the `Checkbox_toggle` and the togegling will stop. But the timer will continue to run. If you check the `Checkbox_toggle` again the timer will toggle again.

Comment: I think this is definitely along the lines of what I'm looking for, but I'm struggling to figure out how I would actually make it actively toggle with that code. I'm trying to implement something that would be along the lines of: `if (Checkbox_toggle.Checked) { Checkbox_control.Checked = !Checkbox_control.CheckedState}`. That gives a syntax error, but I hope that gets the point across

Comment: @ScottMyers almost, simply reverse the `Checked` property and write it back: `Checkbox_control.Checked = !Checkbox_control.Checked;` I added it into my post

Comment: Okay it looks like that's working but there's a strange behavior. The UI only updates the status of the checkbox if I hover over it. For it to then update again I need to move my mouse off the checkbox and then move it back on.  For clarity, if I rapidly move my mouse on and off the checkbox (without clicking), then I can see the box check and uncheck. However, if I do not do this then I cannot see the UI updating. Any ideas for why that might be? If this is out of the scope of this question I can make a new one

Comment: @ScottMyers my fault. You need to call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` because the timer event arrives on a different thread. See my updated answer

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: @ScottMyers no problem. Timers are perfect for such stuff.

Comment: @ScottMyers as a comment on your code: The while loop is executed on the main thread and is called busy waiting. This is why it blocks your GUI. The Method `Delay` doen't wait actually. It simply returns a `Task`, and sets up a new timer each time, with which you populate the memory.