# Good way to spawn a temporary thread that does file monitoring?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following scenario that I'm not sure how it's best to handle.

On an ASP.NET MVC 4 system, I have a controller action that calls an external system (in the same network) that, within anywhere between 1 to 10 minutes, will generate 3 XML files and place them on a folder on the same server where the ASP.NET MVC app is hosted.

At first I thought of using a Windows Service with a FileSystemWatcher to monitor the folder for XML files, but I was asked to suggest an alternative solution, in case installing a Windows Service is not feasible.

I've done very little threading, so I'm not sure what the ideal way to do this is.

In theory, the controller action will call the external system (it's a web service (asmx) call) and then, I want to fire a short-lived thread that will execute for up to 10 minutes, and if it finds .xml files in the folder, it will process them.

Thanks

**-- EDIT, Update**

Brandon's solution works exactly the way I need it, but he says to get the Task.Delay method code from another stackoverflow question, from someone who decompiled the Async library. That did not work for me, so I had to get the Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack NuGet package.

Comment: A Windows Service is definitely a better way to handle this. But if you really need to to it in ASP.NET, [Phil Haack has a good blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) on how to jury-rig it.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I agree, the only problem is that having a Windows Service (which we already had, we just wanted to take it out of the equation if we could) is another additional failure point, something else to configure, getting an installer for it, etc. Brandon's solution works perfectly for what we needed.

Comment: Did you read the blog post I linked to? "works perfectly" is not the term I'd use... "extremely dangerous" fits better IMO.

Comment: I did read it Stephen, it's not 100% safe, but I would say it's 99%, at least for my scenario. I think Phil is a great developer and if he developed and is using this thing (and also got advice for a developer involved with ASP.NET internals), I would say it's safe enough to use it, wouldn't you?

Comment: At the time Phil wrote that blog post, he was a senior program manager for the ASP.NET MVC framework. So if he uses terms like "dangers", "wild", "evil", and "unsupported", then I'd approach the solution with appropriate trepidation.

Comment: I think Phil's just joking with those comments Stephen. Again, I agree it's not 100% reliable, but the Windows Service was less attractive for us because of the maintenance that it implies. As I said, Phil's solution is not perfect, but good enough.

Comment: P.S. `async` and `await` are completely unsupported (as in, their behavior is undefined) on ASP.NET on .NET 4.0. AsyncTargetingPack (and the newer Microsoft.Bcl.Async) do not change this.

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary. Looked you up, apparently you know your async stuff, thanks for adding to the conversation. Question for you, given that Microsoft states in their details section of the AsyncTargetingPack: "The "Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 2012" enables projects targeting .NET Framework 4.0 or Silverlight 5 to use the Async language feature in C# 5 and Visual Basic 11", they don't exclusively say Windows or Library projects, which then means web projects are also supported.

Comment: So I'm just confused as to why you say the behavior is unsupported in ASP.NET. Link I saw: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576

Comment: The async targeting pack provides *library*-level support, which is sufficient for .NET 4.0 Desktop projects as well as SL, WP and PCLs. However, ASP.NET rewrote their `SynchronizationContext` in 4.5, and the ASP.NET team states the [new context is required for WebSockets and `async`/`await`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx).

Comment: Well, again, thanks for sharing your knowledge @StephenCleary. I didn't end up using async/await, I'm just using the targeting pack to get the Task.Delay functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FileSystemWatcher` does not require a thread or a Windows service.  Just create it, set up your event handlers, then set `EnableRaisingEvents` to true.  Then start a timer that expires after 10 minutes and disposes of the watcher.  Something like:

```
private async void RunAfterDelay(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token, Action action)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay, token);
    if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        action();
    }
}

private void RunWatcher()
{

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = "...";
    watcher.Created += (_, e) =>
    {
        if (e.FullPath == "file-you-are-interested-in")
        {
           // cancel the timer
           cts.Cancel();

           // do your stuff
           // ...

           // get rid of the watcher
           watcher.Dispose();
        }
    };

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    // start the timer
    RunAfterDelay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), cts.Token, () =>
    {
        // get rid of the watcher
        watcher.Dispose();

        // do anything else you want to do, like send out failure notices.
    });
}
```

This will start listening to the watcher and if you get what you want, it will dispose of the watcher.  If the timer expires, it will stop the watcher.

The above is targetting .NET 4.5.  If you are targetting 4.0, then first grab the implementation of `Delay` shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9068520/674326

Then change `RunAfterDelay` to this:

```
private void RunAfterDelay(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token, Action action)
{
    TaskEx.Delay(delay, token).ContinueWith(t => action(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Brandon. I'm using .NET 4.0, not 4.5, so I think async and await are not available. Would it be possible to adjust the code to not use async await?

Comment: MVC 4 was designed for .NET 4.5. Maybe you're using MVC 3 on .NET 4?

Comment: No Stephen, I am targeting .NET 4.0 on ASP.NET MVC 4. Try it out :)

Comment: @GR7 - I added some bits to the bottom to suggest the changes for .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Brandon. Let me give this a quick shot and I'll mark as answer if it works :)

Comment: Hey brandon, by TaskEx.Delay I think you might have meant Task.Delay, but the Task class (in .NET 4.0) doesn't appear to have a Delay method. Is this another 4.5 vs 4.0 thing?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out about the Async Targeting Pack (I thought all functionality was included in the framework by default), but adding the NuGet package "Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack", I got the TaskEx functionality. Thank you very much Brandon, you rock.